# What is the latest by which to apply for H4

Tags: h1-visa, h4-visa

My H1 expires in Sep 2018 and I am getting married in Feb 2018. What is the latest by which I can apply for my wife's H4? What is the latest by which she can safely enter the USA?

Comment: The H4 visa is actively being changed right now. I’d try to apply as soon as you can — and if you can afford it, hire a good immigration lawyer.